# How to populate database with fake data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I heard about gems like faker or populator but they are a little bit old (populator does not seem to play well with Rails 3).

So my question is, what do you use to generate fixtures ?

Comment: Singular: datum, Plural: data :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people use [FactoryGirl Rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails), which works nicely with Faker for doing things like random names, to make test data during their tests.

If sometimes you just want to populate your Dev DB with some fake data to make your application work, you can still use FactoryGirl Rails and make a Rake task that will populate some data you need.

Comment: I shudder most times I see random and test together. Unless your tests are probabilistic or you're conducting fuzz or exploratory testing, random data is usually a test smell.

Comment: To be fair, I only said "random" while talking about names. Sometimes you may not care about some aspect of data. If you're testing a method that calculates if it's a user's birthday, and you have a validation that a user *needs* a name, why does it matter what name it is? You can hard code a name in the Factory, or use Faker to make do it for you. Not a big deal sometimes.

Comment: You don't care what the data in name is, but there are code paths under test which do: perhaps length restrictions or valid construction assertions, or not handling certain encodings, or whatever.  When you randomly generate the name and the test fails once every 1000 runs because occasionally the random data violates a constraint, this is a headache for the maintenance programmer.  It's often quite hard to duplicate because the random seed isn't available so just rerunning the test doesn't fail and allow further inspection and debugging.

Comment: That's why you tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in new fixture framework for ruby, take a look on [Fabrication](http://fabricationgem.org/). It's looks like [FactoryGirl Rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) but have more interested features. We are using it with Faker and it's fine. I think it's the best solution nowadays :)